# ssh login doesn't parse .profile or .bashrc properly and is generally being weird

Tags: ssh, login

- First of all it doesn't load my PS1. It just prompts me with a `$`
- The arrow keys instead of doing what they're supposed to do, the just echo things like: `$ ^[[A`

And that makes it very unusable.
A couple of things to consider here:

- This only happens when I login through ssh, it doesn't happen when I login directly to the server.
- One of the users works pretty fine even with ssh; and that's the user that was setup during the installation of the OS (**ubuntu server 14.04**).
- When I `su - otherUser` from within that user that works fine, everything works fine.

Here's the `.bashrc` in case you want to take a look at it (It is the same on all users including the one that works correctly):

```
function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
NO_COLOR="\[\033[0m\]"
#PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$"
export PS1="[\u@\h $YELLOW\W$NO_COLOR]$GREEN\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOR\$ "
```

Here's an output log for when I try to login to the user the **works** properly `ssh -vvv ubuntu@server`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15436267/

Here's an output log for when I try to login to the user the **doesn't work** properly `ssh -vvv adam@server`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15436301/

Comment: What distro? It looks like you don't have TTY for that user (for some reason). Can you post the commands which you use to connect to the server with `-vvv` switches for both users (working and not working)? There will be some difference.

Comment: Seems almost the same. Then check the potential errors in the server log and permissions of `/home`, /home/adam`, `/home/ubuntu` and the respective `*rc` and `.profile` files. Also what is in `sshd_config` on server might be interesting.

Comment: The shell problem might be debugged by logging what the shell is doing, e.g. via `ssh -l thatuser -t thathost "bash -x"` or such.

Comment: What's the output of `getent passwd mega | cut -d : -f 6-`? What makes you think that your `.profile` isn't executed (your `.bashrc` clearly isn't, but I don't see any clue that your `.profile` isn't executed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you describe (very basic prompt only, arrow keys don't work) are consistent with having `/bin/sh` as your login shell, rather than `/bin/bash` as expected. `/bin/sh` is a small shell designed to run scripts fast, not to be comfortable for interactive use.

To check what your login shell is, run

```
getent passwd $USER
```

This displays a list of colon-separated fields, the login shell is the last one.

If the login shell is not the one you want, run [`chsh -s /bin/bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html).

The reason you're getting bash in a terminal may be that somewhere in your configuration you're setting the `SHELL` environment variable to bash. Terminal emulators normally run the program indicated by `SHELL`, falling back to the login shell if `SHELL` is not set.

Comment: It is very often that /bin/sh is symlink to somthing else (/bin/bash on centos7 or /bin/dash on Ubuntu 14.04, for example), so it should be checked first. Dash doesn't not process .bashrc

Comment: @BobanP. `/bin/sh` is dash on Ubuntu. Dash does not process `.bashrc`.

Comment: ok, so that's the reason why it's not working as expected. You should update the answer.

Comment: @BobanP. What do you think I should add to the answer? I'm already explaining that `/bin/sh` doesn't have the expected interactive features.

Comment: /bin/sh is dash. Dash manual pages says that if dash is started as login shell it reads /etc/profile and ~/.profile. ~/.profile should source ~/.bashrc but that should be checked.

Comment: @BobanP. No, `.profile` should most definitely not source `.bashrc`. That would cause problems in the very common case where `.profile` is executed by a shell that is not bash and is not interactive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37264/discussion-between-boban-p-and-gilles).

Comment: Why doesn't this cause the same problem when he logs in directly, rather than through `ssh`? Shouldn't the local login also use his configured login shell?

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the case. for some reason the `/etc/passwd` had an empty shell field. I guess that's because I created the users using useradd. I changed the configuration of useradd at `/etc/default/useradd` and changed the default shell to `/bin/bash`.
For some reason `chsh` did not work. I had to change the shell field at the `/etc/passwd` manually. but it did work after all. :))

Comment: _"/bin/sh is a small shell designed to run scripts fast, not to be comfortable for interactive use."_ - `/bin/sh` is (a replacement for) the [Bourne Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), which was most definitely designed for interactive use, as well as scripting. Just because it is spartan by today's standards and isn't used much interactively today doesn't mean it wasn't designed for that ;)

Comment: @marcelm On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is dash, which was explicitly designed to be fast and use little memory. Being a Bourne shell replacement is only an indirect objective: modern shells implement POSIX requirements, which is a little more than what the Bourne shell has to offer. Dash wasn't designed for interactive use: the intent of its authors (well, for a significant part of its development history at least) was to use dash for scripting and bash for interactive use.