# Problem with characters in SSH with MingW32 and not super-user

Tags: ssh

I am connecting to my server with SSH from Windows 10 with MINGW32 (Git).

When I connect and user the **root user** everything works correctly but when I login with another user and use special characters like **backspace** or similar, the console shows **incorrect characters** and I can't erase.

An example:

```
root@sample:/# php -r 'echo "I can write\n";'
I can write
root@sample:/# php -r 'echo "I can erase without problem\n";'
I can erase without problem
root@sample:/# su sample
$ php -r 'echo "I can write some characters";'
I can write some characters
$ php -r 'echo "I cant erase and I cant use the up arrow for repeat the last command";'
I cant erase and I cant use the up arrow for repeat the last command$
$ ^[[A  : not found
$ : 16:
$ trying erase^H^H^H^H^H
```

With Putty I have not problems.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271036/ssh-login-doesnt-parse-profile-or-bashrc-properly-and-is-generally-being-weir/271139#271139 : you're getting sh instead of bash when you do `su sample`. What are you doing that's different with PuTTY? Are you doing ssh directly to this account? Have you configured PuTTY to run bash explicitly? What is that account's login shell (see the linked answer)?

Comment: Your answer is the correct!! I am using Webmin and it has the default shell to /bin/sh. The root user have /bin/bash and works. Putty not change the shell when login to another user. Put the answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The other user may have an `stty` command in their shell initialization.  For most terminals, there are two choices for the `stty erase` character: ASCII backspace (`^H`) and delete (`^?`).  Since you are logging in temporarily and (probably) should not modify their shell initialization, the quick work around is to type

```
stty erase
```

followed by a space, then <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

where *backspace* is whatever your terminal happens to send when you press the "backspace" key.

After that, "backspace" should continue to work on that session as long as you are connected.

Comment: Thanks! And for up arrow? (^[[A)

Comment: That's different: usually it is due to difference in `TERM` (some terminal descriptions initialize arrow keys to *application mode*, some don't).